# Simple linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let's say $A$ is an orthogonal $2\times2$ matrix over $\bf C$ and not diagonalizable over $\bf C$.
Why then the determinant of $A$ must be $1$?

I guess I'm missing something easy...

Comment: Do you have an example of an orthogonal matrix not diagonalizable over the complex numbers?

Comment: No I don't why?

Comment: Why would you ask, if you didn't have an example, or some other reason for believing it to be true? Why do you believe it to be true?

Comment: This is a multiple choices question when I need to mark to correct answer and according to my teacher this is a correct answer

Comment: Well, it's correct in the sense that the hypothesis is false so any conclusion is true. But it would be just as true to say that if $A$ is orthogonal and not diagonalizable over the complex numbers then its determinant must be $17$. I wonder whether the question is not supposed to be about diagonalizability over the *reals*?

Answer (score 3):

Orthogonal matrices are *normal*, and [all normal matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalMatrix.html) are diagonalizable over the complex numbers.

Comment: Was trying to prove it and it got so messy. This is so amazingly clean!

Answer (score 1):

This is false, e.g. $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Forgot to mention matrix is orthogonal

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** It is well known that every ***real*** orthogonal matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. Actually, every $2\times 2$ ***complex*** orthogonal matrix is also diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. See theorem 1.2.3 of [this thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.5519&rep=rep1&type=pdf), for instance. So, your assertion can be viewed as a vacuous truth.